# Sphinx inline include

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to use the `.. include::` function inline, but I can only get it to actually include the file I want if I separate it with two new lines from the previous text.

Before anyone asks, the file I want to include is a protocol number, so no, it doesn't benefit from a new line, at all. I want to be able to change it easily so I can use it on multiple places of my documentation. I guess that an example would be "We currently use the protocol (proto.txt)." I'm new to Sphinx and rst, so maybe there is a very obvious solution I haven't found.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Sachith What I said in the OP, I couldn't figure anything other than separating it with newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline includes are not possible with Sphinx.

However, you can define **global** [aliases](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions) (substitutions) in the `rst_epilog` variable of your [build configuration file](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-rst_epilog).

For example, you can add the following lines to your `conf.py`file:

```
rst_epilog = """
  .. |version| replace:: 4.1
  .. |protocol| replace:: httpx
"""
```

Now, you can access the variables `|version|` and `|protocol|` from any .rst file within your project, for example like this:

`Version |version| uses the |protocol| protocol.`

becomes

`Version 4.1 uses the httpx protocol.`

If other parts of your software require `protocol` (or other variables) to be specified in a specific file or format, you can write a script to read it from there as a variable into the Sphinx configuration file.

Comment: Thank you! As I said I imagined there was some sort of way, really appreciated! :)