# RST + Sphinx: definition list with `include` directives

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a definition list (HTML `<dl>`) of separate pages, and I'm trying to store both the page link (`<dt>` + `<a href>`) and page description (`<dd>`) in separate files for maintainability.

I would like the resulting HTML to look like a single definition list with multiple entires:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>
        <a href="path/page1.html">Page 1 name</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            Page 1 description
        </p>
    </dd>
    <dt>
        <a href="path/page2.html">Page 2 name</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            Page 2 description
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

I reviewed every other RST + `include` page I could find here. The closest was [Sphinx inline include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187030/sphinx-inline-include), but it didn't seem directly applicable.

### What *almost* works: each combo as a single `include`

In this scenario, I store the page title (+ link) and description as a single definition list entry.

```
.. seealso::

  .. include:: /file1.rst

  .. include:: /file2.rst
```

Where the `filex.rst` files are super simple and look like this:

```
`Page x title <path/pagex.html>`_
  Page x description.
```

The problem is the resulting HTML has multiple definition lists with one entry each, not a single list with multiple entries. Example:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>
        <a href="path/page1.html">Title 1 text</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            Page description 1 text.
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>
        <a href="path/page2.html">Title 2 text</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            Page description 2 text.
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

### What didn't work #1: individual `include`s

This resulted in an empty See Also box (no definition list at all):

```
.. seealso::

  .. include:: /title1.rst
    .. include:: definition1.rst

  .. include:: /title2.rst
    .. include:: definition2.rst
```

Where `titlex.rst` looked like:

```
`Page x title <path/pagex.html>`_
```

And `definitionx.rst` looked like:

```
Page x description.
```

BTW, placing additional lines between the `include` statements didn't change anything.

### What didn't work #2: using substitutions

I tried to use substitution syntax. (The `titlex.rst` and `definitionx.rst` are identical to the non-working example 1 above.)

```
.. seealso::

  |title1|
    |definition1|

  |title2|
    |definition2|

.. |title1| include:: /title1.rst

.. |definition1| include:: /definition1.rst

.. |title2| include:: /title2.rst

.. |definition2| include:: /definition2.rst
```

This resulted in bizarre HTML:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>
        <a href="#id9"><span class="problematic" id="id10">|title1|</span></a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            <a href="#id11"><span class="problematic" id="id12">|summary1|</span></a>
        </p>
    </dd>
        <dt>
        <a href="#id13"><span class="problematic" id="id14">|title2|</span></a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
            <a href="#id15"><span class="problematic" id="id16">|summary2|</span></a>
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Did you try in your "What almost works" example to remove the blank line between the include directives? Perhaps the extra line is a signal to Sphinx to create a new definition list or paragraph?

Comment: Hi Steve, I did try that. (I tried every newline/space combo you can imagine!) Sadly, no dice.